# Twilio functions request time out

Tags: function, twilio

Hello I want to get data from Apis and check record from it in loop which runs 6 time and return data for 3 days. But I faced a request time out issue when make this function run from studio flow. After hit 3 to 4 times function start working fine. Then on the next day we facing same issue when we make several tries again that working fine. I think I have issue with my code or something else. Please give me best solution that how I resolve this timeout issue.

My code for function is here:

```
const axios = require('axios');
exports.handler = async (context, event, callback) => {
  // Create a new voice response object
  const twiml = new Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();

 let Max_date = new Date();
 // console.log("today:",Max_date); 
 let Min_date = new Date();
  var date = new Date();
  Min_date.setDate(Min_date.getDate()-3);

 var toText = event.phone.toString(); //convert to string
  
   var originalphone="("+toText.charAt(2)+toText.charAt(3)+toText.charAt(4)+")"+" "+toText.charAt(5)+toText.charAt(6)+toText.charAt(7)+"-"+toText.charAt(8)+toText.charAt(9)+toText.charAt(10)+toText.charAt(11);
 var OrderId=0;
   var OrderUrl="";
   var fullfillmentstatus=null;
   var fullfillment=0;
  try {
      
      for(let j = 0; j<6 ; j++)
      {
         
         var Url1="Api_Url";
       
         
         const response = await axios.get(Url1);
        
       for (let i = 0; i <250 ; i++) 
       {
           //console.log(i);
           if(response.data.orders[i]!=null)
           {
               if(response.data.orders[i].shipping_address!=null)
               {
                    if(response.data.orders[i].shipping_address.phone==originalphone || response.data.orders[i].shipping_address.phone==event.phone)
                     {
                   
                         OrderId=response.data.orders[i].order_number;
                         OrderUrl=response.data.orders[i].order_status_url;
                         fullfillmentstatus=response.data.orders[i].fulfillment_status;
                         
                        if(fullfillmentstatus==null)
                        {
                              fullfillment=0;
         
                        }
                        else
                        {
                               fullfillment=1;
       
                        }
                         i=249;
                        j=19;
                   }
               }
               
           }
           
           if(response.data.orders[i]==null)
           {
               
               i=249;
           }
          
      
       }
    Min_date.setDate(Min_date.getDate()-3);
    Max_date.setDate(Max_date.getDate()-3);
   
     console.log(Max_date); 
        //console.log(j); 
    }
    return callback(null, {fullfillments: fullfillment,orderid: OrderId,orderurl:OrderUrl});
   
  } catch (error) {
    
    console.error(error);
     return callback(error,twiml);
  }
  
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Twilio Functions has a [10 second execution time limit](https://www.twilio.com/docs/runtime/functions/invocation#callback-function). My guess is that making a request 6 times and looping through the results to process them is taking longer than that.

I am guessing also that you run the loop 6 times to request the same API as you are waiting for a result that might not be there the first 5 times. If that is the case, then I would recommend rewriting your function to only call the API once and then return either a failure or a success if you have the data you were looking for. Then, in your Studio flow, you can make the request and follow it with a Split widget. That Split widget checks to see if you have the data. If it does, the flow continues, but if it doesn't, you loop around to the function widget again and call the function that calls the API again. You can also add in a Set Variable widget that you can use as a counter and another Split widget so that you don't go round that loop forever.

Comment: Thanks evangelist that's work nice for me i successfully resolved my issue for request timeout

Comment: Awesome! If this answer helped, please do mark it as correct. If it didn't help, please add an answer of your own to share how you did resolve the issue. Thanks!